# javascript onchange not selected give value

Tags: javascript

onchange not beselected or nochange give value how to?
look my example

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
  <option value="500">Worldwide</option>
  <option value="150">EMS</option>
  <option value="350">DHL</option>
  <option value="200">UPS</option>
  <option value="75">Postal</option>
</select>
<input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="+Add" />
<script>
function leaveChange() {
        var leaveValue = document.getElementById("leave").value;
        var shippingItems = document.getElementById("item_ship");
            if (leaveValue != ' ') // ??
                shippingItems.innerHTML = leaveValue;
            else
                shippingItems.innerHTML = this.value;
}
</script>
<div id="item_ship"></div>
```

i think my question is clear. If opening the page given value is `<option value="500">Worldwide</option>` value is `500` how do get at div id

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you describe the exact behavior that you want your page to have?

Comment: `this` refers to `window scope` in your example

Comment: @RayonDabre, my mistake, disregard my previous answer

Comment: @jason  it clear try code no value after onchange dropdown get value i want `<option value="500">Worldwide</option>` this auto selected but no value in javascript function

Comment: @Henoktwo - So you want the value in `item_ship` to automatically be set to '500' when the user lands on the page?

Comment: yes right `<option value="500">Worldwide</option>` is 1st value already selected @aphextwix

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Worldwide` to be selected as an automatic option, just add this to your HTML :

```
<option value="500" selected>Worldwide</option>
```

To have the value of `item_ship` set to the selected value of Worldwide on page load, you could try this :

**HTML**

```
<select id="leave" onchange="leaveChange()">
  <option value="500" selected>Worldwide</option>
  <option value="150">EMS</option>
  <option value="350">DHL</option>
  <option value="200">UPS</option>
  <option value="75">Postal</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>

 function setItemShip() {
    var leaveValue = document.getElementById("leave");
    var itemShip = document.getElementById("item_ship");
    // sets the value of #item_ship to selected value
    itemShip.innerHTML = leaveValue.options[leaveValue.selectedIndex].value;
 }

  window.onload = setItemShip;

</script>
```

Here's a live code example - [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/maL1sr37/5/)

Comment: i do but not be functioned `<div id="item_ship"></div>` value empty if land on the page

Comment: @Henoktwo - you also want the value of `Worldwide` to appear in `item_ship` ?